Solubility of lead carbonate
Lead nitrate reacts with sodium carbonate to form lead carbonate, if sodium carbonate is in excess will the white precipitate of lead carbonate dissolves ? Like in lead nitrate reaction with excess of sodium hydroxide.

Try to understand why lead nitrate forms a precipitate with sodium hydroxide first and dissolves in excess second. Then concentrate on whether this could happen with carbonates.

When lead salt reacts with sodium carbonate, a white precipitate of a mixture of lead carbonate and lead hydroxide forms:
$$\ce{2Pb^2+ + 2CO3^2- + H2O -> Pb(OH)2 \downarrow + PbCO3 \downarrow + CO2 ^}$$
Lead carbonate is insoluble and doesn't easily gets dissolved. In the reaction, there is also lead hydroxide, so if the reaction condition is very alkaline , it will tend to form lead hydroxide complexes and other polymeric lead hydroxide. Around slight basic condition and at high concentration of carbonate (exceeding lead concentration), it can tend to can form $\ce{[Pb(CO3)]2^2-}$. There is also chance to form mixed hydroxide-carbonate salts. This topic is actually studied during measurement of lead concentration in groundwater (see reference)

Ref.: Geological Survey Water-supply Paper, U.S. Government Printing Office, 1982
